# Rain Cover for the Case Logic SLRC-206?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-bag, weather

I am on the outlook for a camera bag. I found the [Case Logic SLRC-206](http://www.caselogic.com/en/US/Products/Camera-Cases/View-All/SLRC_-_206_-_BLACK_-__-_SLRCameraLaptopBackpack). It seems very good for my intended use:

- Holds a 15" laptop
- Medium Size: Good for some lenses and misc stuff (Filters ect.) not too big.
- Easy access to camera
- Tripod Strap
- Not that heavy

My only concern is that there is no rain cover for this bag. Living in Denmark, I see rain a lot and I would like, not to be worried about my equipment getting wet.

Do you know any rain covers that will fit this bag. Or do you have an alternative bag that might be better in rainy weather?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when a bag does not have its own rain cover it is problematic to find a rain cover that fits properly. I would suggest to find a similar bag (your criteria) that has a rain cover included.

Comment: I found another bag "Lowepro Fastpack 350 AW", It's pretty nice and  meets my criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Tamrac offers a [laptop backpack](http://www.tamrac.com/3385.htm) with an additional  [rain cover](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000PA5O4M) and additional [tripod straps](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0009PEUR0).

I have an older model of this type and the zippers have a latch over it that basically prevents rain from coming in, very effective. The rain cover is more something I would think to be needed in torrential downpours.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Kata Bumblebee range.  I saw these at B&H in New York and was very impressed.  Not cheap but i think this would last you quite a while.

Pictures of the bumblebee [Kata - Bumblebee](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=kata%20bumblebee&client=firefox-a&hs=cye&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&channel=fflb&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=rlKGUeGqNYatiQerjoBY&ved=0CEkQsAQ&biw=1024&bih=667)